# Puppet: Enumerating all users within a group

Tags: ldap, puppet, user-accounts, groups, facter

Is there any way to enumerate an array of all users within a group within Puppet, either as a fact or something so I can do something like this?

```
$users = enumusers('wheel')
each($users) |$user| {
    dostuff{"stuff:$user":
        user=>$user
    }
}
```

Users are managed through LDAP, but I be able to have Puppet pick up LDAP users and make all of them consistent.

Comment: You could use a custom fact that queries all users from LDAP, then have a template that iterates over the entries in that fact. But that's a Bad Idea(TM). What is your actual goal here?

Comment: My actual goal is to be able to create a new user in LDAP (say for a new hire), and be able to have Puppet configure permissions and an environment for that user without having to do user management through Puppet (which is kludgy at best)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of kludgy, but you could have an external fact generator that enumerates all of your users, and creates a `user_USERNAME` fact for each one.  You could then use this in conditional statements in your Puppet manifests:

```
if $user_lars {
  file { '/home/lars':
    ensure => directory,
    owner => lars,
    group => lars,
    mode => 0700,
  }
}
```

Writing [external facts](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/custom_facts.html) is easy; you can use whatever languages you're comfortable with and it could be as simple as:

```
#!/bin/sh
getent passwd | cut -f1 -d:
```

...depending on your environment.

You know, looking at this makes me feel guilty, but it's the best I can come up with right now.

Comment: I considered something similar by having a custom function query LDAP directly, but that didn't seem "right". If nothing more puppetty comes up, I'll take this answer.

Comment: This is still the best way to do this kind of thing in Puppet nearly 4 years later...